# FTP URL username and paassword with special characters

Tags: java, ftp, special-characters

It looks like standard Java URL class FTP client cannot work with username having characters such as "@" and ".".

The username I get from my hosting provider is something like "username@domain.com", so the whole URL looks like "ftp://username@domain.com:password@domain.com". It works perfectly with all ftp clients, but apparently not with Java. Any suggestions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried to encode these characters, i.e. `username%40domain.com:password`?

```
String ftpUser = URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
String ftpPass = URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
String url = String.format("ftp://%s:%s@domain.com", ftpUser, ftpPass);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it worked after I moved ":" out from the URLEncoder.encode()

Comment: i have the same problem, could you please tell me what you mean with ( I moved ":" out from the URLEncoder.encode() ) ????

This solution cause an error : "Unable to connect to server: Unable to log in to server (PASS): "