# Ruby OpenURI FTP not working when username has spaces

Tags: ruby, ftp, open-uri

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 and am running the following command:

```
open("ftp://user name:password@datafeeds.domain.com/1234/1234.txt.gz")
```

which returns:

> URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?)

Encoding the user name (replacing spaces with %20) does not work either:

> Net::FTPPermError: 530 Invalid userid/password

The URI works fine in all browsers and FTP clients tested - just not when using OpenURI. Also, using Net::FTP (which is wrapped by OpenURI) works fine as well:

```
require 'net/ftp'
ftp = Net::FTP.new
ftp.connect("datafeeds.domain.com", 21)
ftp.login("user name", "password")
ftp.getbinaryfile("/1234/1234.txt.gz")
```

Any idea why the OpenURI method does not work, while the Net::FTP method does? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By definition in [the specification](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt), URL user names only allow these characters:

```
user                   alphanum2 [ user ]
[...]
alphanum2              alpha | digit | - | _ | . | +
```

Browsers are notorious for ignoring the specifications so saying they support it isn't a good proof. They *shouldn't* per the spec.

If cURL supports them, then use the [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) gem and see if that'll let you use them.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if you saw, but I edited the post about 5 min ago to include the fact that Net::FTP works fine. We are using that for now, but would ideally like to use just OpenURI (since Het::HTTP will be used as well in the app).

Comment: Typo above: Het::HTTP =>> Net::HTTP

Answer (score 1):

According to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280964/ftp-url-username-and-paassword-with-special-characters), you should be able to just escape the special characters in your username and password. You could do something like:

```
login = URI.escape('user name') + ':' + URI.escape('password')
open("ftp://#{login}@datafeeds.domain.com/1234/1234.txt.gz")
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but in this case converting spaces to "%20" results in an FTP authentication error.

Comment: What happens if you try `CGI.escape` style escaping, e.g., `open("ftp://user+name:password@datafeeds.domain.com/1234/1234.txt.gz")`?

Comment: Same issue when using "user+name" in place of "user name".

Answer (score 1):

`open-uri` seems broken in that matter. I had the similar issue with the password which contained `#` character.

I ended up bypassing `set_password`, which doesn't allow `#` char in password, by setting URI's `@password` instance variable directly.

```
uri = URI.parse(...)
if uri.password
  uri.instance_variable_set "@password", "password_with_#_char"
end
open(uri) # now this works fine
```

It's hacky, but does the job.